# SRAM Rival eTap AXS in «semi-automatic» mode

Tags: sram, shifting

I am an almost complete noob in electronic shifting, so pardon my possibly stupid question.

I've read somewhere that **sram rival etap** has a «semi-automatic» shifting mode, which keeps jumps to next up/down gear smallest possible. They call it «sequential» shifting, I think, but I'd like a confirmation that I got it right.

To explain what I mean, let assume that your bike has an XG-1250 12-speed cassette and 35/48T crankset, and you're currently riding on `2-7` gear combo (2nd front, 7th rear gear). Your transmission ratio is 2.824.

Your track now goes a tiny bit uphill and you feel you want just a bit easier gearing now. If you switch to `2-6` with tx ratio 2.526 by just going one sprocket down on the cassette, that will be far from optimal, the jump is too big. Optimal gearing with your configuration will actually be `1-9` with tx ratio 2.692 — the closest smaller value to the one of your current `2-7` gear combo.

So question is whether rival can be configured to do the shifting from `2-7` to `1-9` automatically when only hitting downshifting button once. That is, again, from 2nd front and 7th rear sprocket to 1st front and 9th rear cog. Both derailleurs would need to shift at the same time.

Oh, and if this indeed works as described aboce, do derailleurs switch **simultaneously** or in sequence, one after another?

Thanks.